# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile

Tags: java, struts

We are deploying our Struts application in WAS6. While initializing we are getting error as below:

```
org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init> Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.util.LocalStrings', returnNull=true
[10/13/11 8:10:30:999 CDT] 00000016 PropertyMessa I org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init> Initializing, config='org.apache.struts.action.ActionResources', returnNull=true
[10/13/11 8:10:31:317 CDT] 00000016 PropertyMessa I org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources <init> Initializing, config='ApplicationResources', returnNull=true
[10/13/11 8:10:31:394 CDT] 00000016 TilesPlugin   I org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin init Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''.
[10/13/11 8:10:31:395 CDT] 00000016 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0100E: Did not realize  init() exception thrown by servlet action: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1003)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:482)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.ActionComponentServlet.init(ActionComponentServlet.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:175)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:910)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:832)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:550)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:572)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:816)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2120)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)

[10/13/11 8:10:31:399 CDT] 00000016 ServletWrappe E   Deregister the mbean because of uncaught init() exception thrown by servlet action: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception thrown by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:286)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:175)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:910)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:832)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:550)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:572)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:816)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2120)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1003)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:482)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.ActionComponentServlet.init(ActionComponentServlet.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:175)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:910)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:832)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:550)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:572)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:816)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2120)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
, 
[10/13/11 8:10:31:401 CDT] 00000016 WebExtensionP E   Error occured while preparing the servlet for initialization. 
javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception thrown by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:286)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:175)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:910)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:832)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:550)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:572)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:816)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2120)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1003)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:482)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.ActionComponentServlet.init(ActionComponentServlet.java:104)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:227)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1308)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:175)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:910)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:832)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:550)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:387)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:293)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1137)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:572)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:816)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2120)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve this?

Comment: I don't do Struts, but Google gives [quite some hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22java.lang.NullPointerException+at+org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile%22) on this particular exception. You may find some of them helpful.

Comment: Most likely something in your config file. Which we can't see. If it's not obvious by looking at it, I generally start by commenting large chunks out to try to isolate where the config error is.

Answer (score 1):

Recently we faced this problem while adding a new module. As we found our `web.xml` contains new modules struts config mappings, but the actual files were not present in the location.